# How does wireshark calculate the TCP length when there is no header indiciating such?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

In wireshark, you have this field:

```
[TCP Segment Len: 1380] # How is this calculated?
```

My assumption is using the IP headers plus TCP's.

```
TCP Segment Len = IP Total Length - IHL - TCP Header Length
```

In the packet trace, the values filled in would look like

```
[TCP Segment Len: 1380] = 1420 - 20 (5 bytes) - 20 (5 bytes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TCP segment length isn't specified in the header because it's redundant. All packet data following the TCP header (and options) is TCP segment data.

It's length can be calculated by taking the IP packet length and substracting the lengths of IP header + options and TCP header + options.

Comment: Why is the TCP segment length redundant?

Comment: Because it can be calculated from other header fields or by simply counting the bytes that follow the TCP header.